# Showing message of the week's day

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, message

I am trying to implement a small script, to display in order the messages form an array, for every week's day is another array. I started it but I got stuck.
The code is

```
let daySun = ['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'];
let dayMon = ['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'];
let dayTue = ['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'];
let dayWed = ['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'];
let dayThu = ['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'];
let dayFri = ['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'];
let daySat = ['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'];

let dayWeek = new Date().getDay();
//How to get

setInterval(function(){
// 1. to compare name of the day with above arrays
// 2. if today is Sun, then messages from daySun array to be displayed in  order
// 3. and so on for every day of the week
// 4. I want to add fadeIn or fadeOut, or a animate class from  animate.min.css

},1000);

//html for messages is <p id="day-msg"></p>
```

Comment: what have you tired so far?

Comment: what you want display all days? only if the day get to be fadeIn fadeOut?

Comment: why are you using setInterval?

Comment: @mrs68tm I think you should accept answer that helped you also original answer and not copied one from other. It'll make the community stronger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done refer [js fiidle](https://jsfiddle.net/569zf3ao/)

html

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.2/animate.min.css">
  <!-- or -->
</head>


<h1 class="animated infinite fadeOut" id="day-msg"></h1>
```

java script

```
let day ={"sun":['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'],"mon":['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'],"Tue":['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'],"wed":['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'],"thu":['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'],"fri":['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'],"sat":['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4']};


let dayName = new Date().toString().split(' ')[0].toLowerCase()

currentIndex = 0;
setInterval(function(){

document.getElementById("day-msg").innerHTML = day[dayName][currentIndex++];
 if(currentIndex >= day[dayName].length){
   currentIndex= 0;
  } 
},1000);
```

Comment: but why u did't accept my answer as correct answer? any thing went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Create object of messages for days as:

```
let messages = {
    sun: ['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'],
    mon: ['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'],
    tue: ['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'],
    wed: ['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'],
    thu: ['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'],
    fri: ['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'],
    sat: ['msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4']
}
```

get current day name as:

```
let dayName = new Date().toString().split(' ')[0].toLowerCase();
```

find the messages for the day:

```
let currentMessages = messages[dayName];
```

store index of message in array while displaying messages, initially `0`

```
let currentIndex = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    console.log(currentMessages[currentIndex]);
    currentIndex++;
    // below code to loop your messages, if you want to close messages clear interval.
    if(currentIndex >= currentMessages.length) {
        currentIndex = 0;
    }
},1000);
```